# Выполнение условия при отметке в двух (либо более) checkBox'ах

Tags: c#

Делаю программку по учёбе, что-то вроде курсовой: написать тест на C#, на чекбоксах, в трех уровнях сложности:
1. выбор одного варианта ответа из пяти представленных;
2. двух (или более) вариантов одновременно;
3. ввод ответа с последующей проверкой на правильность.
Стандарт, в общем. Самый простой уровень написал легко, самый сложный - тоже.
А вот как сделать, чтобы условие правильности ответа выполнялось, когда нужно выбрать два или три правильных варианта ответа одновременно?
Пытался сделать вот так:

```
int rcount = 0; // число правильных ответов
string right1 = "";
string right2 = ""; // определяем правильные ответы
....
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox[] CB = { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4, checkBox5 };
    foreach (CheckBox cb in CB)
    {
       if (cb.Checked && cb.Text == right1 && cb.Text == right2) rcount++;
    }
}
```

но не выходит, условие не выполняется, `rcount` не увеличивается. В коде, который опустил, производится опрос чекбоксов, и переменные `right1` и `right2` соответствуют правильным вариантам ответа. И, если выбраны правильные варианты, нужно, чтоб выполнялось увеличение счётчика верных ответов. Судя по всему, идиотский вопрос, но не знаю, как сделать, чтобы это работало. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтоб условие выполнялось при двух или более вариантах ответа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в задаче сказано `двух (или более) вариантов` - это значит, что надо определить массив/коллекцию для вариантов, а не отдельный right* для каждого варианта.

p.s.
Добавил [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475585/196972) -- WinForms приложение, в котором можно указывать любое количество вопросов и правильные ответы.

Comment: Всё-таки, я не умею задавать вопросы /_- Ввёл в заблуждение неправильной постановкой вопроса, судя по всему, вас. Я хотел сделать тот самый коварный тип тестов, когда есть 5 вариантов ответа, и нужно выбрать из них все правильные сразу, иначе - ответ не засчитывается правильным. То есть, нужно не выбирать либо-либо, а выбрать всё. Вот, надеюсь, так будет правильнее и понятнее звучать вопрос :) Прошу прощения

Comment: Но я посчитал, что такого будет достаточно, потому что правильных ответов будет максимум три из пяти, что позволяет ввести три переменных вместо коллекции.

Comment: _"Ввёл в заблуждение неправильной постановкой"_ -- не проблема. исправил ответ.

Comment: Фактически, я мог бы сделать так: `if (cb.Checked && (cb.Text == right1 && cb.Text == right2))` Это верно?

Comment: Всё, понял. Получилось. Ещё раз пробежался по операторам, осознал, какой я тупица :D

Comment: Создал массив из `right`-ов, даже ещё лучше стало. Теперь можно в любой момент менять правильное количество ответов, не меняя код. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял нужно чтоб счетчик увеличивался в зависимости от количества выбранных ответов!!  Вот так попробуй)

```
CheckBox[] CB = { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4, checkBox5 };

            for (int i = 0; i < CB.Length; i++)
            { 
                if (CB[i].Checked == true)
                {
                    rcount++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Сюда добавте проверку на правильные ответы!

Comment: Кстати да, так тоже можно, остаётся только одну строчку с методом проверки добавить. Спасибо :) Я

Answer (score 0):

Пример для работы с любым количеством вопросов.

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms"

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

var q = @"
вопрос1? true
вопрос2? false
вопрос3? true
вопрос4? true";

var qas = q.Split(new[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(str => {
              var qa = str.Split('?');
              return new { Q = qa[0].Trim(), A = bool.Parse(qa[1].Trim()) };
            });

var f = new Form() { Padding = new Padding(10) };

foreach (var qa in qas) {
    var cb = new CheckBox() {
               Text = qa.Q,
               Tag = qa.A,
               Dock = DockStyle.Top,
               Parent = f
               };
    f.Controls.SetChildIndex(cb, 0);
    cb.CheckedChanged += CheckedChanged;
}

var b = new Button() { Text = "Результат", Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Bottom };
b.Click += (s, e) => {
    var result = f.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                  .Sum(cb => cb.Checked && (bool)cb.Tag ? 1 : 0);
    var expected = qas.Sum(qa => qa.A ? 1 : 0);
    MessageBox.Show(result + " из " + expected);
};

// если надо сразу показывать неправильный выбор
void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var cb = sender as CheckBox;
    var a = (bool)cb.Tag;
    cb.ForeColor = (cb.Checked == true && !a)
                    ? Color.Red
                    : Color.Navy;
}

f.ShowDialog();
```